# What is the purpose of having multiple IPs for one server?

Tags: networking, ip

A matter of curiosity; I've been shopping around for VPS hosting, and I've seen that some services offer 2, 3, 4 or more IP addresses. Why would you ever need this/what is the purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have multiples application that cannot change the listening port, having multiples IP addresses can allow you to have multiples instance of the application without changing the port

Comment: That sounds relatively reasonable.